# Assigning a letter to OEM Partition

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, disk-partitioning

I'm trying to do an exact clone of my laptop. There is an OEM partition that I can't assign a letter to. I'm using DISM, which uses the drive letters to know what to capture.

I was wondering if there was a way to assign a letter to the OEM partition. I've looked at diskpart and assign letter does not work for OEM partitions. I was wondering if there was a work around.

Also I looked into partitions and volumes and it was a bit confusing, how are they correlated? Are partitions subsets of volumes?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure partitions are subsets of volumes, but I can't find verification anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) are storage units used to divide physical disks into smaller, independent parts. Basically they're containers for filesystems. [Volumes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_%28computing%29) are storage units with a filesystem. A volume can be inside a partition, but it's also possible for a volume to span multiple partitions.

As for assigning a drive letter to that particular partition: you need to determine the type of the filesystem inside that partition first. [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) might prove helpful there. Windows can only mount FAT(32) and NTFS volumes. For other filesystems (like Ext2/3/4 or XFS) you're going to need 3<sup>rd</sup> party tools.